# MySQL: How to ORDER BY and SET ids?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I already googled but couldn't find a solution.

I have two columns called `order_id` and `name`. I want to `ORDER BY name` and then `SET` ascending `order_id`.

Like this:

```
order_id   name
1          Arya
2          Herbert
3          Paul
4          Peter
5          Tiffany
```

My id column is `int(4)` and by default value is `0`. It's not `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE`. (It'a also not the main id. Main id is of course `PRIMARY`.

How can I do this with SQL?

Comment: Why would you want to update the id column based on name - surely you would have to rebuild id every time a new name was added, corrected or deleted?

Comment: @P.Salmon No, it's a little bit complicated: You can set a custom order (with html/php script). I want to make a button to reset all the custom order and order by names. It's not really a names column. I don't have to update every time a new name was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For versions < 8.0 you can use this:

```
select @rn := 0;

UPDATE tbl T1
JOIN (select @rn := @rn + 1 rn, `name` from tbl order by `name`) T2
  ON T1.`name` = T2.`name`
SET T1.order_id = T2.rn
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ipfiuui5rGuYFWt6ikT2LJ/1)

Useful article related to your problem: [MySQL UPDATE JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`(MySQL 8.0+):

```
SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS rn
FROM tab
ORDER BY rn;
```

---

Update:

```
UPDATE tab
SET order_id = (SELECT rn FROM (SELECT name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS rn
                                FROM tab)s
                WHERE s.name = tab.name); -- assuming that name is UNIQUE
```

**[DBFidde Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=59c7ea906f3bc254344caebfdd7a7bcf)**

Comment: What is `rn`? I want to `UPDATE` not only `SELECT`.

Comment: I'm getting: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY name) AS rn FROM tab)s WHERE s.name = tab.name)' at line 1`

Comment: @David As I stated this will work only on MySQL 8.0 and above. `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: I'm using `5.6.30 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

As your mysql version is below 8.0 so you have to manually generate orderid
below can help you

```
select  t.*, 
                   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS order_id from 
            (
            select * from
             tab o order by name asc
            )  as t , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae3fda/3